# Requirements on std::forward_list::remove_if predicates

Tags: c++, list, c++11, language-lawyer, predicate

Consider this code:

```
struct T
{
bool status;
UsefulData data;
};

std::forward_list<T> lst;

lst.remove_if([](T &x) -> bool { return x.status= !x.status; });
```

i.e. switching the status and removing inactive elements in one go.

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/remove) the above code seems to be undefined behavior (emphasis mine):

> ```
> template< class UnaryPredicate >
> void remove_if( UnaryPredicate p );
> ```
>
> `p` - unary predicate which returns true if the element should be removed.
>   The signature of the predicate function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> bool pred(const Type &a);
> ```
>
> The signature does not need to have `const &`, but the function **must not** modify the objects passed to it.
>   The type `Type` must be such that an object of type `forward_list<T,Allocator>::const_iterator` can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to `Type`.

However, the current working draft seems to be less restrictive ([N4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) [forwardlist.ops]):

> ```
> void remove(const T& value)
> template <class Predicate> void remove_if(Predicate pred);
> ```
>
> *Effects:*
>
> Erases all the elements in the list referred by a list iterator `i` for which the following conditions hold: `*i == value` (for `remove()`), `pred(*i)` is `true` (for `remove_if()`). Invalidates only the iterators and references to the erased elements.
>
> *Throws:*
>
> Nothing unless an exception is thrown by the equality comparison or the predicate.
>
> *Remarks:*
>
> Stable (20.5.5.7).
>
> *Complexity:*
>
> Exactly `distance(begin(), end())` applications of the corresponding predicate.

Are there additional restrictions on predicates in other parts of the Standard?

I have tested the above code on a number of compilers and it compiles and seems to work as intended. Do I really need to transverse the list twice?

Comment: We almost certainly imported the requirement from [\[algorithms.requirements\]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/algorithms.requirements#6.sentence-3).

Comment: @T.C. although bad manners, since the iterators of a forward_list are forward_only, I can't imagine a sensible implementation where modifying the object in the predicate would be a problem.

Comment: @RichardHodges The complexity requirement means that it has to apply the predicate exactly once per element anyway. A hostile implementation might iterate through the list with constant iterators though.

Comment: @T.C. Is it allowed to? That would break the contract of forward_list::find_if I think. If you pass mutable iterators to it, you'd expect *iter to be mutable - indeed objects without a const interface would rely on it. 
Additionally, it occurs to me that forward_list::remove_if is not actually an algorithm. It is a member function. In this case, would the restrictions in [algorithms.requirements] apply?

Comment: Tricky indeed. I strongly suspect that they are intended to, but the wording might not be there.

Comment: @T.C. I can't find such an import of [algorithms.requirements] into [cointaners.*], neither in C++11, nor in C++1z n4659.

Comment: When I get some time I'll probably file an LWG issue for this to get clarification one way or the other. While `remove_if` is not particularly problematic, allowing Compare to modify elements with `list::sort` is certainly a horrendously bad idea, and that non-modification requirement is only in found in [alg.sorting].

Comment: Now [LWG 2998](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2998).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The committee's Library Working Group has just moved [LWG issue 2998](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2998) to "Ready" status, essentially confirming that the committee's intent here is that the relevant requirements from Clause 28 (the algorithms clause) apply to the similar list operations. This includes the requirement that the `Predicate` does not apply any non-constant functions.

Once the issue resolution is adopted (which should happen at the next committee meeting), the code in the OP will formally have undefined behavior. Nonetheless, it should generally work as desired barring an intentionally hostile implementation. If an implementation with guaranteed well-defined behavior is desired, it's not too hard to write one manually with iterators and `erase_after`.

Answer (score 2):

In light of the comments under your question, my view is that:

- `forward_list::remove_if` is not an algorithm, and as such does not fall under the rules of [algorithms.requirements].
- [forwardlist.ops] places no restriction on what you may do in the predicate.
- `forward_list::remove_if` is required to apply the predicate exactly once per item in the range.

Therefore, it's strictly legal to modify the object in the predicate in this case, if somewhat anti-social.

#### edit:

In the light of T.C.'s later answer, it won't be legal for long...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45052149/2015579